# Showing content at the top from dom relatively lower z-index?

Tags: html, css

In html code below , Is there any proper solution to show "popup" as toppest element without only changing popup style?

https://jsfiddle.net/cass0sj4/

```
<style>
.layer_one {
   position :relative;
   z-index : 10;
}
.layer_two {
   position :relative;
   z-index : 5;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<div class="layer_one"></div>
<div class="layer_two">
  <div class="popup">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No way. As far I know `z-index` works on parent element. What's the particular reason you're creating this?

Comment: Yep put popup outside of layer 1 and layer 2 and it can be included in the z-indexing and therefore be wherever you want it.

Comment: @LaraBelle  I only can change popup style.  Html file is built from different sources.

Comment: Try to clone it with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Take popup out of layer 1 and layer 2 and you can put it wherever you want it. In this case I added z-index: 9999 to it (and some color to the layer 2 so you can see all containers)

```html
    <style>
    .layer_one {
       position :relative;
       z-index : 10;
       background : blue;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
    }
    .layer_two {
      background: green;
       position :relative;
       z-index : 5;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
    }
    .popup{
      background : red;
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      position : fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left : 0px;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="layer_one">Layer One</div>
    <div class="layer_two">
 
    </div>
         <div class="popup">
         Popup
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't move popup out of layer_two

Comment: You are a bit stuck unless you use some jQuery to grab the popup code and move it somewhere else in the DOM, but that sounds like more than you need to do. Why can't you edit the html/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't achieve what you are looking for just with CSS with the markup you have used.

I have two workarounds for you on this:

#### 1. If you can modify the markup a bit;

Make it like this:

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="layer-1">
      Layer 1
    </div><!-- .layer-1 -->

    <div class="layer-2">
      Layer 2
    </div><!-- .layer-2 -->

    <div class="pop-up">
      Pop-up
    </div><!-- .pop-up -->

  </div><!-- .container -->
```

Since our HTML has become simpler for this particular case of problem; it's easy now to put the pop-up box over the two layers.

```
/* Layer #1 */
.layer-1 {
  z-index: 1100;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* Layer #2 */
.layer-2 {
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: green;
}

/* Pop-up box */
.pop-up {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1300;
  background-color: red;
}

/* Common styles */
.layer-1,
.layer-2 {
  position: relative;
}

.layer-1,
.layer-2,
.pop-up {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/rahul_arora/pen/yMoyKM

#### 2. If you can't touch the markup

If you are allowed to use JavaScript, you can achieve that without touching the markup or even CSS. Here's that bit of JavaScript that moves the `.popup` div to top in the order:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container'), // Reference to the .container div
    layer_one = document.querySelector('.layer_one'), // Reference to the .layer_one div
    popup = document.querySelector('.popup'); // Reference to the .popup div
   
container.insertBefore(popup, layer_one); // Move .popup just above .layer_one
popup.style.zIndex = "2000"; // Increase the z-index to show the .popup floating over others
```

I have a working codepen for you: http://codepen.io/rahul_arora/pen/QpMwvy

Hope that solved the problem for you. Cheers!